# Visual Studio 2015 Installation hangs at Android SDK Setup (API Level 19 and 21) And Level 22

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015

I found a couple post that kept saying to stop the SecondaryInstaller.exe.  That stops the installation of the Android SDK altogether.  What I found that worked and the SDK installed correctly was stopping the Java.exe process.  Everything installed correctly after that process was stopped.

Comment: Really, this is both question and answer.

Comment: Worked for me too, thx. Had to kill java.exe several times for each SDK.

Comment: I wonder what the cause of this is. Somebody should report this to Microsoft...

Answer (score 3):

It is because of Java. Check your machine

```
java -version
```

Your machine have to use java version 8 or the latest.
Otherwise your installation cannot be succeed.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a network issue.  After you kill the process, if you're on a corporate network, you will need to open the Android SDK Manager, go to the options, and specify your company proxy server.  Then do a modify on the VS 2015 install in Control Panel to check the boxes for the Cross Platform Development pieces.  It should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to 
c:\Program files\Android and run android sdk manager.

Check/add the sdk version that you need to use before the new versions (features),

android sdk manager will validate that you need the sdk installed before apply the updates. if you dont have the sdk version then you need to uncheck all the newers features and install the sdk version before, after that you can add/check the newers features you need.

Answer (score 0):

Disable WMM in your internet router. (Bandwidth Control options)
WMM Enable WLAN traffic control. After this function is enabled, the router manages all WLAN devices in your home network and properly allocates Internet access traffic to ensure stable connection speeds for each WLAN device.

If you turn off this feature the data transfer will not be interrupted.

This worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows 7 then you need to download Hyper-v and enable it on "windows features"

Guide and download link:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/schadinio/2010/07/09/installing-hyper-v-manager-on-windows-7/

Relaunch the vs installer again, repair or add features should works now.

Hyper-v is a virtual machine manager.

Microsoft Visual Studio emulator for android needs hyper-v to open the SO.

Microsoft Visual Studio emulator is a fast android emulator.

Hope this can help